# Hawkhost redirecting to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, dns

I need help with domain redirecting. 
I have a website domain with Hawkhost and a blog with wordpress. 
I am trying to redirect my domain to the wordpress site. I have tried changing the DNS settings, Set the CName but it still didn't work. 
Kindly can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Please always remember that DNS changes need time to propagate. Depending on TTL settings of DNS entry it may take from minutes to even over a day.

Comment: We'll need more details to see what's wrong. What's your current DNS configuration? If you're comfortable sharing, what is your domain?

Comment: I have only set CName in my DNS managment for my domain.   Yeah it's okay, the domain name is salesforcejourney.com